# Is there a way to remove the margin between table displayed tables but still have margins between all other elements and tables?

Tags: html, css, markdown, css-tables

So I'm a beginner looking to style html tables I'm using with CSS for an epub3 I'm creating. I'm trying to stack multiple tables after each other without margin but insert a margin between the group of tables and p elements. Any help would be appreciated.

I've gotten the tables to function as I want but can't get them to have a margin between the tables and the following paragraphs. I'm writing the tables in html as part of a markdown document.

[Tables without margin between tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv4Y9.png)

```css
@charset "utf-8";
background-color: #222222;
:root {
  --main-bg-color: #222222;
  --main-color: #eeeeee;
  --alternate-bg-color: #444444;
  --alternate-color: #cccccc;
  --main-border-color: #AAAAAA;
  --table-header-bg-color: #e2e2e2;
  --link-color: #627EC9;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  root {
    --main-bg-color: white;
    --main-color: black;
    --alternate-bg-color: #efefef;
    --alternate-color: #222222;
    --main-border-color: #BBBBBB;
    --link-color: #627EC9;
  }
}


/************ HTML ****************/

html {
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "helvetica neue", helvetica, roboto, noto, "segoe ui", arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4em;
  background-color: #222222;
  color: #eeeeee;
}


/*********** Headers *************/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Nelson Bold", "Lemon/Milk", "Myriad Pro", helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: : 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: : 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: : 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: : 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
}


/************* Images **************/

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 10%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/************** Body ***************/

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #222222;
  color: #eeeeee;
}

@media (max-device-width: 480px) {}

@media (min-device-width: 481px) {
  body {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 600px;
  }
}


/************ VOG ******************/

blockquote {
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 4em 2em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #444444;
  color: #cccccc;
}


/************ Table ****************/

table {
  display: table;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 4em;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

p~table {
  margin-top: 4em;
}

table~p {
  margin-top: 4em;
}

table~table {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

ˇ th {
  padding: .25em .5em;
  color: #222222;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  font-family: "Nelson Bold", "Lemon/Milk", "Myriad Pro", helvetica, sans-serif;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
}

td:nth-child(odd) {
  text-align: left;
  border-right: none;
}

td:nth-child(even) {
  text-align: right;
  border-left: none;
}


/* alternate line color */

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #444444;
}

p~th {
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}

blockquote~p {
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}

p~blockquote {
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}

img~p {
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}

p~img {
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}

p~p {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}


/* Status Table */

.status {
  display: table;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.status td:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 30%;
}

.status td:nth-child(even) {
  width: 70%;
}


/* Geno-r Table */

.geno-r {
  display: table;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.geno-r td:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 50%;
}

.geno-r td:nth-child(even) {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Geno Table */

.geno {
  display: table;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.geno td:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 50%;
}

.geno td:nth-child(even) {
  width: 50%;
}


/* Beast Table */

.beast {
  display: table;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  magin-right: auto;
}

.beast td:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 70%;
}

.beast td:nth-child(even) {
  width: 30%;
}

.article {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 2em;
  color: var(--alternate-color);
  background-color: var(--alternate-bg-color);
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-family: Lemon/Milk, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.ar {
  text-align: right;
}

.al {
  text-align: left;
}

.light {
  background-color: var(--alternate-bg-color);
}

.dark {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}

.note {
  font-size: 50%;
}
```

```html
<p>Han Sen returned to his room, made a fire, and started boiling the black beetle claws and shells in a pot.</p>

<p>Without tools and know-how, he could only use the most primitive methods to process the shells and extract the geno essence.</p>

<p>The shell of a sacred-blood creature would take more than an hour or two to cook, so Han Sen covered the lid and took out the black crystal to take a closer look.</p>

<p>Still, no clues whatsoever.</p>

<p>Suddenly, Han Sen caught a glimpse of the caged green-scaled beast the size of a civet cat in the corner of his room and suddenly had an idea.</p>

<p>Like black beetles, this green-scaled beast was an ordinary creature. Han Sen used to prey on them and bring them back to cook and eat to increase his geno points.</p>

<p>But later, green-scaled beasts no longer increased his geno points, so Han Sen didn’t eat the last beast and forgot about it. Surprisingly, it was still alive.</p>

<p>He grabbed the moribund green-scaled beast from the cage, hesitated for a moment and was about to feed the black crystal to the beast.</p>

<p>To his surprise, seeing the black crystal, the dying green-scaled beast gathered all its strength to stretch out its tongue, roll the black crystal back into its mouth and swallow the whole crystal.</p>

<p>&#8220;There is indeed something magical about the black crystal!&#8221; Han Sen was stunned and found that the green-scaled beast seemed considerably more lively after swallowing the crystal, its four claws scratching and head moving to bite Han Sen’s
  hand, which was on its neck.</p>

<p>Han Sen threw the green scaled beast back into the cage and carefully watched it. The beast, which hadn’t fed for days, completely recovered its vitality, thrashing and scratching wildly in the cage, just like it had when it was first caught.</p>

<p>Han Sen sat across from the cage and watched the movements of the green-scaled beast. He had a guess, and if he was right, he might have obtained something incredible—something more exciting than a sacred-blood creature.</p>

<p>But Han Sen was afraid he was wrong, so he could only stare at the green-scaled beast anxiously, hoping to see the change that he desired.</p>

<p>Han Sen nervously stared intently and did not realize that he was starving until he smelled bone broth from the pot.</p>

<p>Looking at the time, he noticed almost 24 hours had passed. Rising to check the black beetle shell in the pot, he saw the golden color of the shell had been boiled off and the broth had become golden. It smelled so good that the hungry young man’s mouth
  watered.</p>

<p>About to scoop up a bowl of soup, Han Sen suddenly heard iron breaking from the cage of the green-scaled beast. He quickly turned around and saw the green-scaled beast had bitten off an iron bar of the cage and stretched out his head from the inside.</p>

<p>Its light green scales had now completely turned a dark green color. Its teeth had become sharp and the tips of its four claws were like iron hooks. The beast was about to come out of the cage.</p>

<p>Han Sen was pleasantly surprised and pulled out the dagger from his waist. He rushed to the front of the cage and stabbed the dagger into the lower belly of the green-scaled beast. With a turn of the dagger, the green scaled beast stopped struggling.</p>

<blockquote>
  <p>&#8220;Primitive Creature Green-Scaled Beast Killed. No Beast Soul Gained. Eat The Flesh Of The Primitive Green-Scaled Beast To Gain Zero To Ten Points Randomly.&#8221;</p>
</blockquote>

<p>The strange voice sounded in Han Sen’s mind and left him stunned.</p>

<p>&quot;Primitive green-scaled beast … Primitive creature … So the crystal can really make these creatures evolve … &quot; Han Sen was overwhelmed with joy and did not know how to react.</p>

<p>After a long time, he suddenly cut open the green-scaled beast with the dagger and uncovered the crystal as big as a pigeon egg. Taking no heed of the blood on it, he kissed the crystal twice and then wiped it clean, holding it in his hands like it was
  a great treasure.</p>

<p>&quot;The crystal was really the reason the black beetle became a sacred-blood creature … If the green-scaled beast had continued to evolve, could it have become a sacred blood creature too? &quot; Han Sen almost dared not think about it, because it was
  just too amazing.</p>

<p>He was so excited that his hands were trembling while holding the crystal. He bit his tongue and cried out of pain so as to know that it really was not a dream.</p>

<p>After remaining excited for quite a while, Han Sen carefully put the crystal away, gobbled up the shell broth, and gained another sacred geno point, bringing his geno point count to eight.</p>

<p>Without tools and means, his primitive method couldn’t extract all geno essence from the shell, but it was good enough that he gained one sacred geno point.</p>

<p>Han Sen realized that he had gained a sacred-blood beast soul of a black beetle when he killed the golden black beetle, and he quickly accessed his profile.</p>

<table class="status">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Han Sen</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>Unevolved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lifespan</td>
    <td>200 years</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Han Sen: Not evolved. -->
<!-- Status: None -->
<!-- Life span: 200 years. -->

<table class="geno-r">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Geno Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Required to Evolve</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>Han Sen returned to his room, made a fire, and started boiling the black beetle claws and shells in a pot.</p>

<p>Without tools and know-how, he could only use the most primitive methods to process the shells and extract the geno essence.</p>

<p>The shell of a sacred-blood creature would take more than an hour or two to cook, so Han Sen covered the lid and took out the black crystal to take a closer look.</p>

<p>Still, no clues whatsoever.</p>

<p>Suddenly, Han Sen caught a glimpse of the caged green-scaled beast the size of a civet cat in the corner of his room and suddenly had an idea.</p>

<p>Like black beetles, this green-scaled beast was an ordinary creature. Han Sen used to prey on them and bring them back to cook and eat to increase his geno points.</p>

<p>But later, green-scaled beasts no longer increased his geno points, so Han Sen didn’t eat the last beast and forgot about it. Surprisingly, it was still alive.</p>

<p>He grabbed the moribund green-scaled beast from the cage, hesitated for a moment and was about to feed the black crystal to the beast.</p>

<p>To his surprise, seeing the black crystal, the dying green-scaled beast gathered all its strength to stretch out its tongue, roll the black crystal back into its mouth and swallow the whole crystal.</p>

<p>&#8220;There is indeed something magical about the black crystal!&#8221; Han Sen was stunned and found that the green-scaled beast seemed considerably more lively after swallowing the crystal, its four claws scratching and head moving to bite Han Sen’s
  hand, which was on its neck.</p>

<p>Han Sen threw the green scaled beast back into the cage and carefully watched it. The beast, which hadn’t fed for days, completely recovered its vitality, thrashing and scratching wildly in the cage, just like it had when it was first caught.</p>

<p>Han Sen sat across from the cage and watched the movements of the green-scaled beast. He had a guess, and if he was right, he might have obtained something incredible—something more exciting than a sacred-blood creature.</p>

<p>But Han Sen was afraid he was wrong, so he could only stare at the green-scaled beast anxiously, hoping to see the change that he desired.</p>

<p>Han Sen nervously stared intently and did not realize that he was starving until he smelled bone broth from the pot.</p>

<p>Looking at the time, he noticed almost 24 hours had passed. Rising to check the black beetle shell in the pot, he saw the golden color of the shell had been boiled off and the broth had become golden. It smelled so good that the hungry young man’s mouth
  watered.</p>

<p>About to scoop up a bowl of soup, Han Sen suddenly heard iron breaking from the cage of the green-scaled beast. He quickly turned around and saw the green-scaled beast had bitten off an iron bar of the cage and stretched out his head from the inside.</p>

<p>Its light green scales had now completely turned a dark green color. Its teeth had become sharp and the tips of its four claws were like iron hooks. The beast was about to come out of the cage.</p>

<p>Han Sen was pleasantly surprised and pulled out the dagger from his waist. He rushed to the front of the cage and stabbed the dagger into the lower belly of the green-scaled beast. With a turn of the dagger, the green scaled beast stopped struggling.</p>

<blockquote>
  <p>&#8220;Primitive Creature Green-Scaled Beast Killed. No Beast Soul Gained. Eat The Flesh Of The Primitive Green-Scaled Beast To Gain Zero To Ten Points Randomly.&#8221;</p>
</blockquote>

<p>The strange voice sounded in Han Sen’s mind and left him stunned.</p>

<p>&quot;Primitive green-scaled beast … Primitive creature … So the crystal can really make these creatures evolve … &quot; Han Sen was overwhelmed with joy and did not know how to react.</p>

<p>After a long time, he suddenly cut open the green-scaled beast with the dagger and uncovered the crystal as big as a pigeon egg. Taking no heed of the blood on it, he kissed the crystal twice and then wiped it clean, holding it in his hands like it was
  a great treasure.</p>

<p>&quot;The crystal was really the reason the black beetle became a sacred-blood creature … If the green-scaled beast had continued to evolve, could it have become a sacred blood creature too? &quot; Han Sen almost dared not think about it, because it was
  just too amazing.</p>

<p>He was so excited that his hands were trembling while holding the crystal. He bit his tongue and cried out of pain so as to know that it really was not a dream.</p>

<p>After remaining excited for quite a while, Han Sen carefully put the crystal away, gobbled up the shell broth, and gained another sacred geno point, bringing his geno point count to eight.</p>

<p>Without tools and means, his primitive method couldn’t extract all geno essence from the shell, but it was good enough that he gained one sacred geno point.</p>

<p>Han Sen realized that he had gained a sacred-blood beast soul of a black beetle when he killed the golden black beetle, and he quickly accessed his profile.</p>

<table class="status">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Han Sen</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Status</td>
    <td>Unevolved</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lifespan</td>
    <td>200 years</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Han Sen: Not evolved. -->
<!-- Status: None -->
<!-- Life span: 200 years. -->

<table class="geno-r">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Geno Points</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Required to Evolve</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Requirements for evolution: 100 geno points. -->

<table class="geno">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Geno Points Gained</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ordinary Geno Points</td>
    <td>79</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sacred-Blood Geno Points</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Geno points gained: 79 geno points; 8 sacred geno points. -->

<table class="beast">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Beast Souls Gained</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sacred-Blood Black Beetle</td>
    <td>Armor</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Beast soul gained: Sacred-blood black beetle. -->
<!-- Type of sacred-blood black beetle’s beast soul: Armor. -->

<p>&#8220;What would the armor of sacred-blood black beetle’s beast soul look like?&#8221; Before Han Sen finished the thought, a golden shadow shot out of thin air, looking exactly like the golden black beetle.</p>

<p>The golden black beetle flew to Han Sen&#8217;s chest, turned into a golden liquid and started to cover his whole body. In the blink of an eye, Han Sen&#8217;s whole body, together with his hair, was all wrapped up.</p>

<p>The streamlined gold armor was full of power and impact, and covered his whole body as if it were a suit of gothic Medieval armor instilled with improved aerodynamics—it looked just like a piece of art.</p>

<p>The whole suit of armor felt full of power and speed, making Han Sen look slender and majestic, as if his whole body were full of explosive power.</p>

<p>With shining metallic luster, the armor was gorgeous and had a solid texture. At first glance, it was even somewhat like the gold cloth worn by Golden Saints.</p>

<p>The difference between the gold cloth and the beast soul armor was that the armor covered the head and body completely, with only a few gaps in the joints where different pieces overlapped, just like the black beetle itself, which was the only weakness
  of the beast soul armor.</p>

<p>Han Sen moved around in the armor and there was no feeling of heaviness or clumsiness. Instead he felt that his body had become a little lighter and full of energy.</p>

<p>&#8220;Indeed, this was armor from a sacred-blood beast soul. It is way more gorgeous than the ones from primitive beast souls that I often have seen at Steel Armor Shelter.&#8221; Han Sen felt ecstatic. He used to envy people in armor of primitive beast
  souls and had never thought he would get a suit of a sacred-blood beast soul one day. </tr>
</p>

</table>
<!-- Requirements for evolution: 100 geno points. -->

<table class="geno">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Geno Points Gained</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ordinary Geno Points</td>
    <td>79</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sacred-Blood Geno Points</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Geno points gained: 79 geno points; 8 sacred geno points. -->

<table class="beast">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Beast Souls Gained</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sacred-Blood Black Beetle</td>
    <td>Armor</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!-- Beast soul gained: Sacred-blood black beetle. -->
<!-- Type of sacred-blood black beetle’s beast soul: Armor. -->

<p>&#8220;What would the armor of sacred-blood black beetle’s beast soul look like?&#8221; Before Han Sen finished the thought, a golden shadow shot out of thin air, looking exactly like the golden black beetle.</p>

<p>The golden black beetle flew to Han Sen&#8217;s chest, turned into a golden liquid and started to cover his whole body. In the blink of an eye, Han Sen&#8217;s whole body, together with his hair, was all wrapped up.</p>

<p>The streamlined gold armor was full of power and impact, and covered his whole body as if it were a suit of gothic Medieval armor instilled with improved aerodynamics—it looked just like a piece of art.</p>

<p>The whole suit of armor felt full of power and speed, making Han Sen look slender and majestic, as if his whole body were full of explosive power.</p>

<p>With shining metallic luster, the armor was gorgeous and had a solid texture. At first glance, it was even somewhat like the gold cloth worn by Golden Saints.</p>

<p>The difference between the gold cloth and the beast soul armor was that the armor covered the head and body completely, with only a few gaps in the joints where different pieces overlapped, just like the black beetle itself, which was the only weakness
  of the beast soul armor.</p>

<p>Han Sen moved around in the armor and there was no feeling of heaviness or clumsiness. Instead he felt that his body had become a little lighter and full of energy.</p>

<p>&#8220;Indeed, this was armor from a sacred-blood beast soul. It is way more gorgeous than the ones from primitive beast souls that I often have seen at Steel Armor Shelter.&#8221; Han Sen felt ecstatic. He used to envy people in armor of primitive beast
  souls and had never thought he would get a suit of a sacred-blood beast soul one day.</p>
```

Comment: What do you want actually please attach screenshot or wireframe...

Comment: ![](https://imgur.com/a/KGkIsUa)

I'm trying to have no spacing between tables but have a margin between tables and everything else.

I'm using CSS to control the size of the td elements depending on the class of table, or otherwise I'd put everything in the same table but different chapters have certain fields and others don't. If there's a better way to do this I'm all ears.

Comment: You want to give space between last table and p tag?

Comment: The tables appear in random order throughout the novel with different tables included in different chapters. I'm trying to find a way to create a margin around tables (plural) without creating a margin between tables.

Comment: and without having to add <br></br> or </br> everywhere as that seems to be bad form.

Comment: What if add div as parent of all tables? like all table show within div tag. If this is okay i will write code for you, using div tag i will give margin bottom to last table.

Comment: If that will work inside a markdown document, I'd really appreciate it. I might have bitten off a bit more than I can handle but It's an interesting exercise to learn.

Comment: //   In HTML file add this div with class as parent element of tables

<div class="my-tables">
    <table class="beast"></table>
    <table class="beast"></table>
    <table class="beast"></table>
</div>


// In CSS add this code

.my-tables table {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.my-tables table:last-child{
   margin-bottom: 50px;
}


Try this if it works let me know (i will add it as answer of this question), If not i will give you another solution.

Comment: That works! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, Vote and accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In HTML file add this div with class as parent element of tables

```
<div class="my-tables">
   <table class="beast">
   <table class="beast">
</div>
```

> In CSS add this code

```
.my-tables table { 
    margin-bottom: 0px; 
} 
.my-tables table:last-child { 
   margin-bottom: 50px; 
}
```